# Elastic beanstalk error: Command failed on instance. Return code: 1

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my django app on aws but i keep getting the following error:

> [Instance: i-********] Command failed on instance. Return
>   code: 1 Output:
>   (TRUNCATED)....6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py",
>   line 285, in state_forwards "%s.%s has no field named '%s'" %
>   (app_label, self.model_name, self.old_name)
>   django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: classroom.itembatch has no
>   field named 'width'. container_command 01_migrate in
>   .ebextensions/db-migrate.config failed. For more detail, check
>   /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Here's my db-migrate.config file

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: django_school.settings
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I change this ?

Comment: It is possible you are modifying `width` field / column of `classroom.itembatch` model while this field is not yet created. Mb its creation step is present in migration file but after modification, not before?

Comment: Have you managed to find the solution to this question? I would be happy to know how to solve this because I have the same problem